# Salesforce Community Error - sObject type 'Report' is not supported in describeCompactLayout

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

We have created Dashboard and it is exposed to community user. Dashboard is visible to community user but when we click on dashboard to see selected data it opens report with below Exception-

> Looks like there's a problem. 
>   INVALID_TYPE: sObject type 'Report' is not supported in describeCompactLayouts.

Answer (score 1):

This error appears because you have not added a Report object page. You may follow these steps to fix this error

1. Go to Communities -> Builder
2. Add new page by clicking non settings icon at the the top.
3. Create a new object page for Report